# Android get resource ID in lambda function returns wrong ID

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

I am using material buttons and use the OnButtonCheckedListener in a MaterialButtonToggleGroup. In the listener callback I want to check which button was checked.

```kotlin
view.findViewById<MaterialButtonToggleGroup>(R.id.trainingWeightButton)
    .addOnButtonCheckedListener {_, resId, isChecked ->
        viewModel.isTrainingWeightValid = resId == R.id.trainingWeightButtonYes && isChecked
    }
```

But `R.id.trainingWeightButtonYes` has some weird value.

If I use the following code it works fine.

```kotlin
val trainingWeightButtonYesId: Int = R.id.trainingWeightButtonYes
view.findViewById<MaterialButtonToggleGroup>(R.id.trainingWeightButton)
    .addOnButtonCheckedListener {_, resId, isChecked ->
        viewModel.isTrainingWeightValid = resId == trainingWeightButtonYesId && isChecked
    }
```

I have absolutely no idea why the second approach works, but the first one doesn't.

Does anybody know what the difference is? Is this some Kotlin specific stuff here?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "has some weird value"?

Comment: It is a ID that no resource in my view has. `R.id.trainingWeightButtonYes=1000206` and `resId=2131231292`. The first ID does not seem to be like a usual ID. It is too short...

Comment: There is no “usual ID”. It can be any integer in the value range for Int. I can’t see any reason for why the two bits of code you posted would behave any differently from each other.

Comment: But as I said there is a difference in these. In the first snippet `R.id.trainingWeightButtonYes == 1000206`. In the second one `R.id.trainingWeightButtonYes == 2131231292`.